# Python Scipy for 2D extrapolated spline function?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, spline, extrapolation

I'd like to write an extrapolated spline function for a 2D matrix. What I have now is an extrapolated spline function for 1D arrays as below. [scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.html) is used.

```
import numpy as np 
import scipy as sp 

def extrapolated_spline_1D(x0,y0):
    x0 = np.array(x0)
    y0 = np.array(y0)
    assert x0.shape == y.shape 

    spline = sp.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x0,y0)
    def f(x, spline=spline):
        return np.select(
            [(x<x0[0]),              (x>x0[-1]),              np.ones_like(x,dtype='bool')], 
            [np.zeros_like(x)+y0[0], np.zeros_like(x)+y0[-1], spline(x)])

    return f
```

It takes x0, which is where the function is defined, and y0, which is the according values. When x < x0[0], y = y0[0]; and when x > x0[-1], y = y0[-1]. Here, assuming x0 is in an ascending order.

I want to have a similar extrapolated spline function for dealing with 2D matrices using [np.select()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) as in **extrapolated_spline_1D**. I thought [scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline) might help, but I'm not sure how to do it.

For reference, my current version of the **extrapolated_spline_2D** is **very slow**. 
The basic idea is:

(1) first, given 1D arrays x0, y0 and 2D array z2d0 as input, making nx0 **extrapolated_spline_1D** functions, y0_spls, each of which stands for a layer z2d0 defined on y0;

(2) second, for a point (x,y) not on the grid, calculating nx0 values, each equals to y0_spls[i](y);

(3) third, fitting (x0, y0_spls[i](y)) with **extrapolated_spline_1D** to x_spl and returning x_spl(x) as the final result.

```
def extrapolated_spline_2D(x0,y0,z2d0): 
    '''    
    x0,y0 : array_like, 1-D arrays of coordinates in strictly monotonic order. 
    z2d0  : array_like, 2-D array of data with shape (x.size,y.size).
    '''    
    nx0 = x0.shape[0]
    ny0 = y0.shape[0]
    assert z2d0.shape == (nx0,ny0)

    # make nx0 splines, each of which stands for a layer of z2d0 on y0 
    y0_spls = [extrapolated_spline_1D(y0,z2d0[i,:]) for i in range(nx0)]

    def f(x, y):     
        '''
        f takes 2 arguments at the same time --> x, y have the same dimention
        Return: a numpy ndarray object with the same shape of x and y
        '''
        x = np.array(x,dtype='f4')
        y = np.array(y,dtype='f4') 
        assert x.shape == y.shape        
        ndim = x.ndim 

        if ndim == 0:    
            '''
            Given a point on the xy-plane. 
            Make ny = 1 splines, each of which stands for a layer of new_xs on x0
            ''' 
            new_xs = np.array([y0_spls[i](y) for i in range(nx0)]) 
            x_spl  = extrapolated_spline_1D(x0,new_xs)
            result = x_spl(x)

        elif ndim == 1:
            '''
            Given a 1-D array of points on the xy-plane. 
            '''
            ny     = len(y)            
            new_xs = np.array([y0_spls[i](y)                 for i in range(nx0)]) # new_xs.shape = (nx0,ny)       
            x_spls = [extrapolated_spline_1D(x0,new_xs[:,i]) for i in range(ny)]
            result = np.array([x_spls[i](x[i])               for i in range(ny)])

        else:
            '''
            Given a multiple dimensional array of points on the xy-plane.  
            '''
            x_flatten = x.flatten()
            y_flatten = y.flatten()     
            ny = len(y_flatten)       
            new_xs = np.array([y0_spls[i](y_flatten)         for i in range(nx0)])         
            x_spls = [extrapolated_spline_1D(x0,new_xs[:,i]) for i in range(ny)]
            result = np.array([x_spls[i](x_flatten[i])       for i in range(ny)]).reshape(y.shape)
        return result      
    return f
```

Answer (score 4):

I've done a similar work called GlobalSpline2D [here](https://github.com/pig2015/mathpy/blob/master/polation/globalspline.py), and it works perfectly under either liner, cubic, or quintic splines.

Basically it inherits [interp2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp2d), and promoting the usage to 2D extrapolation by [InterpolatedUnivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline). Both of them are scipy internal functions.

Its usage should be referred to the [document](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp2d) as well as the [call method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.__call__.html#scipy.interpolate.interp2d.__call__) of interp2d.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've come up with an answer myself, which utilizes [scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html) and is over 10 times faster than my old one.

Here is the function **extrapolated_spline_2D_new**.

```
def extrapolated_spline_2D_new(x0,y0,z2d0):
    '''    
    x0,y0 : array_like，1-D arrays of coordinates in strictly ascending order. 
    z2d0  : array_like，2-D array of data with shape (x.size,y.size).
    ''' 
    assert z2d0.shape == (x0.shape[0],y0.shape[0])

    spline = scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(x0,y0,z2d0,kx=3,ky=3)
    '''
    scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline
    x,y : array_like, 1-D arrays of coordinates in strictly ascending order.
    z   : array_like, 2-D array of data with shape (x.size,y.size).
    '''  
    def f(x,y,spline=spline):
        '''
        x and y have the same shape with the output. 
        '''
        x = np.array(x,dtype='f4')
        y = np.array(y,dtype='f4') 
        assert x.shape == y.shape 
        ndim = x.ndim   
        # We want the output to have the same dimension as the input, 
        # and when ndim == 0 or 1, spline(x,y) is always 2D. 
        if   ndim == 0: result = spline(x,y)[0][0]
        elif ndim == 1: 
            result = np.array([spline(x[i],y[i])[0][0] for i in range(len(x))])
        else:           
            result = np.array([spline(x.flatten()[i],y.flatten()[i])[0][0] for i in range(len(x.flatten()))]).reshape(x.shape)         
        return result
    return f
```

Note: 
In the above version, I calculate the value one by one instead of using the codes beneath.

```
def f(x,y,spline=spline):
    '''
    x and y have the same shape with the output. 
    '''
    x = np.array(x,dtype='f4')
    y = np.array(y,dtype='f4') 
    assert x.shape == y.shape 
    ndim = x.ndim
    if   ndim == 0: result = spline(x,y)[0][0]
    elif ndim == 1: 
         result = spline(x,y).diagonal()
    else:           
         result = spline(x.flatten(),y.flatten()).diagonal().reshape(x.shape)       
    return result
```

Because when I tried to do the calculation with the codes beneath, it sometimes give the error message as:

```
<ipython-input-65-33285fd2319d> in f(x, y, spline)
 29         if   ndim == 0: result = spline(x,y)[0][0]
 30         elif ndim == 1:
---> 31             result = spline(x,y).diagonal()
 32         else:
 33             result = spline(x.flatten(),y.flatten()).diagonal().reshape(x.shape)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/fitpack2.pyc in __call__(self, x, y, mth, dx, dy, grid)
826                 z,ier = dfitpack.bispev(tx,ty,c,kx,ky,x,y)
827                 if not ier == 0:
--> 828                     raise ValueError("Error code returned by bispev: %s" % ier)
829         else:
830             # standard Numpy broadcasting

ValueError: Error code returned by bispev: 10
```

I don't know what it means.

Comment: That is a cryptic error message indeed. The `RectBivariateSpline` is not meant to be called with sequences of points. If you use [`spline.ev`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.ev.html#scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.ev) instead, you can get rid of your loop.